# Edit Text - Showing only bottom line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to show only the bottom line of an Edit Text, but I cannot find any tutorial or something to help me. Can you help me doing it?

Here is an image that shows what I really want to do:

[image]

--

Here is my activity_signin code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

        <!--android:background="@color/white"-->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkRegScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my SigninActivity code:

```
public class SigninActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

EditText email;
EditText password;

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Edit Text
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    //Button
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Button btnLinkRegScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkRegScreen);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some of your code ? Btw default edittext show as above...

Comment: @nicholas edited. I think it's better now, tell me if you want something more. Thx for ur help.

Comment: Your editText background shouldn't put transparent. You remove it should be able to see the bottom line.

Comment: The bottom line is the default behavior of the EditText without background.

Comment: Sure, but if I remove the transparency it shows the lines from beside and above the EditText (all box lines). I want to show only bottom line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only bottom lines from an EditText I need to remove the background attribute: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Here is my EditTexts Code:

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
            />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
            />
```

The rest of the code still the same.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending your Activity from AppCompatActivity, instead of Activity. After that, you need to change the theme that you're using in this activity to have an AppCompat parent, like this one Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Then just use a normal EditText, it should do the trick.

Comment: The app crashes. Should I change something more?

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.podchest.podchest/com.podchest.podchest.SigninActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText'

Comment: you need to import this in your build.gradle file: ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`

Comment: the ~23.0.0~ is the version of your compileSdkVersion

Comment: I've it in build.gradle.

Comment: Why can't I extend AppCompatActivity? I've it in my build.gradle: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can adjust the view right or left based on your need. For this kind of scenario, we can put the image instead of default line or we can have view as a line.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_login"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <View android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
    <!--android:background="@color/white"-->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_login"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <View android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer giving by Mateus is correct 
 
But here is the copied of your code and try is working fine if i remove background...

Here is your outcome.

[image: Your Result]

The code as below: -
Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="abc@email.com"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />

    <!--android:background="@color/white"-->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="***********"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkRegScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Why can't I extend AppCompatActivity? I've it in my build.gradle: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

Comment: What is the error ? and you imported it to the java files ?
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: I've no option to extends AppCompatActivity. It only shows me 'AppCompatPopupWindow' to extend. Should I import something?

Comment: I've tried now to remove only background like you said and it worked as well. I didn't need to change my extends from Activity to AppCompatActivity. I'll answer. Thx for the help.